# $routeChangeSuccess not firing in AngularJS App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am editing an old AngularJS app running 1.3.14

It is using this directive to load a nav bar and change the style of navigation links:

```
app.directive('siteNavbar', ['$location', function($location) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'partials/site-navbar/site-navbar.tmpl.html',
    controller: 'NavbarCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'navbar',
    link: function (scope, elem) {
      //after the route has changed
      scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function () {
        var hrefs = [$location.path()];
        angular.forEach(elem.find('a'), function (a) {
          a = angular.element(a);
          if (-1 !== hrefs.indexOf(a.attr('href'))) {
            a.parent().addClass('active');
          } else {
            a.parent().removeClass('active');
          };
        });     
      });
      $(document).on('click.nav','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
        if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
          $(this).removeClass('in').addClass('collapse');
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

The nav bar loads just fine, but for some reason `scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function () { ... }` is not firing. I have tried using `$scope` `$rootscope` and `stateChangeSuccess` but so far nothing I've tried is working.

I know it's probably something simple, but I can't seem to find it. How do I get this function to fire when a user changes routes?

Comment: Which router are you using? ngRoute or ui.router?

Comment: Loading a navbar is not a route change event.Route change event only get fired when url get changed.

Comment: @Phil I am using ngRoute

Comment: @Ved In the case of this app it's okay that this doesn't happen when the navbar is loaded because it doesn't need to fire until after the route has been changed.